# How to cancel setupIntent?

Tags: ios, node.js, stripe-payments

Upon a user's registration, I have successfully created a setupIntent and attached a payment method to a customer. However, I give the option for the user to add the payment method later in settings by pressing the "Later” button. When this button is pressed I'd like to cancel the setupIntent.

I have the following on my server:

```
exports.cancelSetupIntent = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const clientSecret = data.clientSecret;
  const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.cancel(
      clientSecret
  );
});
```

and I call this from the client when the "Later" button is pressed using the following:

```
func cancelSetupIntent() {
    
    FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("cancelSetupIntent").call(["clientSecret": self.setupIntentParams?.clientSecret]) { (response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to cancel setup intent: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("setupIntent cancelled")
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error saying: "No such setupIntent: "seti_..."

The error displays the same client secret that was created when the page opened.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cancelling a Setup Intent you should be using the Setup Intent ID (seti_xxx), not the Setup Intent client secret (seti_xxx_secret_yyy).

In order to get the Setup Intent ID on your frontend to send it back to your server you have two options:

1. When you initially create the Setup Intent server-side and send the client secret client-side, also send back the ID. Then when you need to cancel the Setup Intent you'd just send back the ID to your server.
2. [Retrieve the Setup Intent client-side](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/retrieve_setup_intent) using the client secret to get the ID before sending it back to your server.